# How to validate multiple comma separated email id's in android?

Tags: java, android

How can i validate multiple comma(,) separated email id's in android.I'm using below code for single email validation.Please can any one help me.

```
static boolean validEmail(String str_newEmail) {


         return str_newEmail.matches("^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@"+ "[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$");
        }
```

Thanking in Advance.

Comment: Maybe split your string by comma before validating each ???

Comment: agreed with Bixi, especially since your regexp doesn't allow comas in email addresses.

Answer (score 5):

Hi There use this code i think this will helps you

```
String str_newEmail = "Bharath@in.com,bharath@appsforbb.co.in";
    String[] test = str_newEmail.split(",");
    for (int i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
        if (!validEmail(test[i])) {
            System.out.println("This is not a vaild email");
            break;
        }
    }
```

validation of email method.

```
    public boolean validEmail(String str_newEmail) {

    return str_newEmail.matches("^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@"
            + "[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$");
}
```

Comment: Congrat's for these easy reputation points .. I didn't even bother to answer with code as this question is a DAY 1 programming lesson.. Did the author really searched / thinked ?

Comment: @Bixi i think he is new that's y he is asking

Comment: @coding devil Yeah and now he'll copy paste your solution without thinking and learning anything ... bah

Comment: @Bixi yes but he tried in different why that's also correct he showed that we achive by that way also i like that one also anyways good one

Answer (score 1):

```
private boolean isValidEmail(CharSequence target) {
    boolean emailflag = false;
    String emailArr[] = target.toString().split("[,]");
    for (int i = 0; i < emailArr.length; i++) {
        emailflag = android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(
                emailArr[i].trim()).matches();
    }
    return emailflag;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You also can use StringTokenizer:

```
String emails = "Bharath@in.com,bharath@appsforbb.co.in";
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(emails, ",");

while (st.hasMoreElements()) {
  String email = st.nextToken();
  if (!validEmail(email)) {
      System.out.println("Invalid email:" + email);
  }
}
```